# How to print from ios simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode5

I am working on app with X-code that generates hundreds of annotations on a map. I need to print this map on a huge poster.My current approach is to  take several hundred screenshots of the map and assemble them into a huge image in Photoshop. I have also considered, printing Google maps and adding the annotations manually afterwards in Photoshop. The problem is that both of my approaches are very time consuming. I wanted to know if there's better way to send a map with annotations to the printer from the ios simulator.
Thanks